# perform projection on list

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I have a list of numbers that I group by the number of occurences. E.g. my list is `{ 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3 }` the grouped list would look like this:

```
{ 
    { Key = 1, Value = { 1, 1, 1 } }, 
    { Key = 2, Value = { 2, 2 } }, 
    { Key = 3, Value = { 3 } } 
}
```

Here´s the code for that grouping:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> groups = input.stream().collect(Collerctors.groupingBy(x -> x));
```

Now for each of those groups I want to get pairs. So for `1` there´s only one pair, the last `1` is omitted. For `2` we also have a single pair, for `3` we don´t have any. So I thought of getting the size of every group and devide it by 2. Finally I need to sum all those results. However I have no idea how to perform such a projection in java. In C# I would do something like this:

```
var result = groups.Select(x => x.ToList().Count / 2).Sum();
```

I suppose in Java I´d use the `collect`-function, but I couldn´t get it:

```
Integer result = groups.stream().collect(...)
```

Comment: What are the expected outputs?

Comment: @YCF_L I want to get the number of pairs. So the expected of the above surely is 2, one pair of 1 and one of 2.

Comment: The C# tag is misleading, if you don't search a C# solution. And you are aware of, you don't need to store your subcollections, if key and item is the same ? A list of " 10 one's, 7 two's, 5 three's", and so on would be more useful.

Comment: *Now for each of those groups I want to get pairs. So for 1 there´s only one pair, the last 1 is omitted*... your logic of pairing doesn't really make much sense in practice, why not pair the second and the third 1? When you already know, *I thought of getting the size of every group and devide it by 2*, all you need is the frequency as pointed out by Holger as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you can chain a `counting` `Collector` to `groupingBy`, so that the values of the `Map` will be the number of elements of each group.

Then you can `Stream` over the values, divide by 2, and compute the sum.

```
input.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),Collectors.counting()))
     .values()
     .stream()
     .mapToLong(i -> i/2)
     .sum();
```

This returns `2` for the sample input.

Comment: What s this `Function.identitx()`? Is that similar to `x -> x`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere yes

Comment: you could use `mapToLong(i -> i/2)` instead of the two step `map` & `mapToLong(Long::longValue)`. If not, I suggest at least swapping the two lines, to avoid an other step of autoboxing.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using `Collectors.summingInt`:

```
Integer result = groups.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.summingInt(x -> x.getValue().size() / 2)
```

Comment: Does `Map` have a `stream()` method? I just looked at the Javadoc of the latest Java version, and couldn't find it. Perhaps you meant `groups.entrySet().stream()`?

Comment: @Eran Yeap, that´s what I ment. Thanks for the hint.